# Вставки нескольких записей одним запросом

Tags: php, mysql

Вывожу нужные данные из первой таблицы БД:

```
$strSQL = "SELECT * FROM first WHERE day='$textday'
```

И хочу занести часть этих данных и дополнительные данные (например дату) во вторую таблицу БД в таком виде:

```
INSERT INTO
second (user_id, dates, visited)
VALUES
(25, "2017-09-27", 1), 
(26, "2017-09-27", 1), 
(30, "2017-09-27", 0)
```

Как сгенерировать все строки **VALUES**, чтобы они выводились в таком виде (25, "2017-09-27", 1) из массивов, которые я беру из таблицы **first**, а также дополнительные данные? И чтобы строки вставлялись в запрос, до тех пока есть что вставлять.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Выбрать и вставить можно так:

```
INSERT INTO second (user_id, dates, visited)
  SELECT F.user_id, '2017-09-27', F.visited
  FROM first AS F
  WHERE F.day='$textday';
```

Если нужно именно строк нагенерировать, то как-то так:

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT (CONCAT('(', F.user_id, ', "2017-09-27", ', F.visited, ')') SEPARATOR ', ')
FROM first AS F WHERE day='$textday'
```